# chef bootstraping ec2 uses the wrong ip in future

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

We mainly do not use ec2 but we do have a few servers. Normally I will bring up a new blank box and boostrap it using the public ip:

```
knife boostrap -N my-new-ec2-box -x root 123.456.789.0
```

I will then run chef-server on the box once it is bootstraped to install the required software. However in the future when I want to run a command on all my boxes using chef knife is unable to connect to the ec2 because it is using the ec2 private address:

```
knife ssh 'do something' -x www-data -a ipaddress
```

is there a way to get knife to use the public ip 123.456.789.0
 which I originally used?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-a public_ip_address` to get the public address.  This attribute is set by the ohai plugin for ec2.  In some cases, particularly when your node is in a VPC, you will need to ensure your bootstrap command includes the `ec2` hint in order to enable that plugin to run.  So you'd do:

```
knife bootstrap -N my-new-ec2-box --hint ec2 -x root 123.123.123.123
```

AND

```
knife ssh 'do something' -x www-data -a public_ip_address
```

Comment: thanks. However most of our boxes are not ec2 and so they don't have the public_ip_address attribute. Is there a simple way around that?

Comment: If you want a single knife command that will work for ALL of your nodes, then you can either ensure they all have resolvable hostnames and use -a fqdn, or you can have a recipe that sets an attribute for you like: `node.set[common_ip] = node['public_ip_address'] || node['ipaddress]`